# Lubuntu 32 bit not showing installed Logitech Media Server

Tags: lubuntu, software-center, logitech, squeezebox

I am new to Lubuntu attempting to make a music source out of an old Dell 386. I downloaded Logitech Media Server v7.7.6, Debian/Ubuntu Linux (77 mb). Logitech Media Server also known as LMS. After download, I used GDebi Package Installer. All seemed to go well. But I cannot find the application now. It isn't in the Software Center. When I use the Software Center search it returns no search result. The downloaded file, named logitechmediaserver7.7.6all.deb is in the Downloads folder. But I cannot find the actual application to run.

Perhaps I should reinstall WindowsXP. The install worked just fine with that operating system on the same computer.

I saw a post about this problem another user had and the solution offered was that LMS is always running in the background and to access it one would go to a web address bar and type in "http://**IP address**:9000", which gets one to one's online LMS account. It's not the solution I'm looking for. I want to access the desktop app of LMS. Any thoughts? ~ thanks

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Debian NEQ Ubuntu. It's off topic here per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 & 16.10) & other Linux distributions" There are many significant differences between Ubuntu & Debian. Until you install 100% standard Ubuntu or a Ubuntu 'flavour' http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours many folks here will suggest you visit Debian Support at http://www.debian.org/support or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Many servers are accessed and configured by the http page.  Cockpit, Plex, webmin, etc.  They are designed that way so that you can run your server headless and still configure the server applications themselves.  LMS is no different and there isn't a desktop app for it.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.  If you want a desktop app, you can look into writing one of your own, but the company that makes LMS does not have one.

Comment: Close voters, the question here does state that they are running Lubuntu and that they downloaded the LMS for Debian/Ubuntu.  Please read the question again.

Comment: This might help, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188506/how-to-install-logitech-media-server-squeezebox-server?rq=1 .  Win XP should not be used if connected to internet.  Did you have a desktop app for this on XP?  Quite a few companies will have a GUI for Windows, but only CLI for Linux.

Comment: I realize that there were problems in my post. I am currently using Squeezebox Duet, which uses Logitech Media Server (LMS) and home wifi network to stream music to my stereo system from either an Internet service or from stored music on a computer. I cannot get the Dell with Lubuntu operating system and LMS installed to be seen by the Squeezebox controller, which I thought it would once I had installed LMS. And I can’t find the LMS software on the Dell so I can’t mess with any settings. I’ll follow the clues you all gave me. I'm new to this. Thanks.